Unable to force user to update on Android when using InappUpdate
i am using in_app_update to force use to update the app but i keep getting this error
I/PlayCore( 9527): UID: [10190]  PID: [9527] AppUpdateService : requestUpdateInfo(money app)
I/PlayCore( 9527): UID: [10190]  PID: [9527] AppUpdateService : Already connected to the service.
I/PlayCore( 9527): UID: [10190]  PID: [9527] AppUpdateService : Initiate binding to the service.
I/PlayCore( 9527): UID: [10190]  PID: [9527] AppUpdateService : Failed to bind to the service.
[log] PlatformException(TASK_FAILURE, Failed to bind to the service., null, null)


I would recommend you to do the following , do a small endpoint the return the minimum allowed app version , and when the app is starting you check that with your current app version and  if app version is less , then you block the way and use any plugin to point to your app in google play and app store

also check github repo ,  some people mentioned that there is issue with force update
